# Assume that $S=\{(x,y): x-y=0\}$. Find the projection formula $P_S$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Q: Assume that $S$={$(x,y): x-y=0$}. Find the projection formula $P_S$.

I'm a bit stuck on where to even begin? Any help would be great!

Comment: $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The way we like to project onto an $n$-dimensional subspace of an inner-product space is:

(1) Find an orthonormal basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ of $S$, then
(2) Project $x$ onto $S$ via $\mbox{proj}_S(x) = \langle x, e_1 \rangle e_1  + \cdots + \langle x, e_n \rangle e_n$.

Comment: Note that $S$ is the line $y = x$. What is a normal (perpendicular) vector to $S$?. Find that vector, then divide it by its length to get the unit normal vector $\hat n$. Then the projection is just $P_S(v) = v - (v\cdot \hat n)\hat n$

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks for the reply! Would the norm vector be $<1,-1>$ and the length is sqrt(2)? so the unit norm is $<1/sqrt(2), -1/sqrt(2)>$? Also, what does $v$ represent in your formula?

Comment: yes and yes. $v$ is an arbitrary vector. The formula is how you can calculate the projection of $v$ onto the plane. The projection of $v$ onto the normal line is given by $(v\cdot \hat n)\hat n$. Subtract that from $v$, and what is left over is the projection of $v$ onto the plane.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ohhhh I get it! Thank you for your help! <3